# Laravel - app with 'Calendar' view & attendance of users approach

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm, eloquent

I've got 'behavioral' problem with approach to Attendance system.

I have database like this:

```
Users:
- increments: id,
- string: name,
- string: email,

Attendance:
- increments: id,
- integer: user_id,
- string: type,
- date: start,
- date: end,
```

I want to print it in table, where `thead` is an iteration of days of the month(I'm using for loop and iterate through days in month), `1st` column in `2nd` is an User name, and rest of columns in this row are the attendance "things" like box with different color, depends of attendance type.

My question is that: what's the best approach? Store attendance like I do or 'divide' the range to single attendance and do like this:

```
Attendance:
- increments: id,
- integer: user_id,
- string: type,
- date: date_of_attendance.
```

I've got issue with displaying it (User model hasMany Attendances), and I do not have an idea how to simplify it.

Should I use 'inside model' function to retrieve the data and parse it before passing it to view like (User model):

```
public function filterAttendance()
{
    return $this->attendance()->whereBetween('start', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()])->orWhereBetween('end', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()])->orderBy('start', 'ASC')->get();
}
```

In view I do `foreach` through all `$users`, then inside it `foreach` through all `$monthDates`(parsed dates to Carbon from 1st of month to last) and then I try to compare the days of attendance if they in "specific" range.

Also I want to achieve best computational complexity in this example.

Comment: If you can prepare the data before taking it to the view it would be better. Also eager load ll the data if possible and avoid doing any queries in loops.

Comment: I need to add "additional" attribute while retrieving the model. I've used `booted()` method, but I don't have knowledge how to pass this dates to this attribute/property and check it directly excluding too many iterations.